# what is the output of join

Tags: sql

I have two tables a and b having column a and b respectively

```
A      B
1      
1      1
       1
1      1
```

what is the output when i join a to b.

Comment: What was the output when you tried it?

Comment: Create the tables.  Run the query.  Note the output.  If you don't have a database on hand, you can use rextester or sqlfiddle.

Comment: i got 10 rows using any join operation

Comment: I can possible to join columns with duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from a join b #join is same as inner join
on a.a_id=b.a_id
```

i guess you have an id in both of your table , now lets say `a_id` is primary key in your `a` table and its a foreign key in your `b` table. Then if you use a `join` you will get the common records in both tables.